# memorystream not saving all content

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, memorystream

Got a big issue with memorystream in c#. My application gets the html of an email, and parses the src values of the images that are attachments and change those src values to another ones. That works perfectly fine. Problem is i have to save the resultant html in a sharepoint list. and it does, but when i see the content in the sharepoint list, it doesnt show the email, just some part of it. I dont know if the memory stream is not saving the content at all, or if the string am saving the result doesnt have enough capacity for saving what the memory stream is storing. If anyone has any ideas please post them!

```
string SRC = "";
int indice = 0;
//Console.WriteLine(body);

HtmlDocument email = new HtmlDocument();
email.LoadHtml(body);
Console.WriteLine("bodylength: " + body.Length);//original length

foreach (HtmlNode img in email.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
{
    SRC = img.GetAttributeValue("src", null);
    for (int i = 0; i < contentIDS.Count; i++)
    {
        if (SRC.Equals(contentIDS[i].ToString()))
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("contents" + contentIDS[i].ToString());
            indice = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    img.SetAttributeValue("src", urls[indice].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(img.GetAttributeValue("src", null));
}

//se guarda en memoria los cambios hechos en el html y se retorna e tipo string el html con los cambios realizados
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
email.Save(memoryStream);
//memoryStream.SetLength(body.Length);
memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
return streamReader.ReadToEnd();//this is then store in a string when i call this method. The lenght of that string is much much smaller than the original one.
```

Comment: maybe try wrapping the usage of the MemoryStream inside a using() block?

Comment: Are you sure this is not simply an HTML rendering issue? Did you look at the page source? Is the full email there?

Comment: Please don't add "c#" and such to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: This is Html Agility Pack you are using?

Comment: Which HtmlDocument is this?  Neither http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx nor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmldocument(v=vs.95).aspx have a `Save(Stream)` method.

Comment: @Oded yes am sure the html is complete because i print it at the beginning of the application, and then i print the string that contains the result of the memorystream and its much much shorter

Comment: am using htmlagilitypack api @ChrisShain

Comment: That's not what I asked. In sharepoint, when viewing a page that should display the email (following your use of `MemoryStream`), can you see, in the source, the full email or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this by using a `Save` overload which uses a `TextWriter`:

```
HtmlDocument email = new HtmlDocument();
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    email.Save(sw);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

Note that you should always dispose objects which implement `IDisposable` (the simplest way is to wrap them inside `using` blocks as shown here).

Comment: Thanks in this way it works and saves the html in its whole content!! Thanks very much

Comment: I have actually never used this library, I just browsed the [source code](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for the `HtmlDocument` class to see if there is a handier overload. It's a pity there isn't a `ToString` overload (opposite to `LoadHtml`, where you load directly from a string).

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you are getting the whole string back here, and that are not `Flush()`ing a stream somewhere else- probably when you save it to disk.  The code here looks fine.

If you post the function where you save it, my guess is that we'll see the problem there.